# Swift developed code not working in Xcode 8.x or Xcode 7.x

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I open swift2.3 developed project in Xcode 8.x (8.1,8.2.1,8.3.3)it is showing lots of errors of 3rd party files. I did below actions

1. I do pod install then update the pod but after that it is showing around 500 errors in 3rd party framework like alamofire.
2. I tried to configure it in Xcode 7.3 but still not getting error free code and it is showing error in linked 3rd party framework.
3. I tried without update any pod but it is not showing linked files in project and show so many errors

When I open the project in Xcode 8.x it is asking for conversion. I did convert as it suggest and getting lots of errors.

[image: it is showing 15 when I try to resolve them they will increase in any other file like an infinite loop.]

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: it would be more reasonable to actually check-out the latest 3rd party libraries one-by-one while you would do the auto-update on your own code only.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please share how to " check-out the latest 3rd party libraries one-by-one"?

Comment: go and download latest libraries and it should work. While updating the Xcode version keep in mind that Swift is in under development hence keep a copy of working code safe.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do I remove pod and add all files manually download as we were doing previously.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to fix all this manually.

As stated in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561709/8824091) you should expect your code to be broken after a Swift version change.

I suggest you to follow the advice of that post (that is, backup your 2.3 version, and carefully do all the conversion, which will be tedious and slow).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think apple provide some other solution except manually solving lots of errors.

Comment: The problem is, Xcode doesn't really know what you want to do with your code, but it tries to convert it to the new syntax, which may lead to errors. You can reduce the number of errors, but there will always be.

Comment: Migrating Swift 2 to 3 is pretty painful, unfortunately.